# Points-based scoring systems for non-automotive sports with more than two competitors played over a season

Tags: scoring

In Formula 1 racing, [the following scoring system](https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/rules-regs/Classification_Race_distance_and_Points.html) is used to determine the winning drivers and constructors:

> - 1st : 25 points
> - 2nd : 18 points
> - 3rd : 15 points
> - 4th : 12 points
> - 5th : 10 points
> - 6th : 8 points
> - 7th : 6 points
> - 8th : 4 points
> - 9th : 2 points
> - 10th : 1 point

Both [NASCAR](https://www.nascar.com/en_us/news-media/articles/2016/11/28/how-nascar-series-points-are-awarded.html) and [Supercars](https://www.v8scglobal.com/inside-supercars/the-supercars-points-system/) use a similar system.

Are there any non-automotive sports, involving more than two competitors, played over multiple rounds (e.g. a season or tournament) that use points-based scoring systems to determine the seasonal winner?

To clarify, by multiple rounds, I mean that at the end of these rounds, an overall winner is announced - and these results are not carried over to further events.

Comment: Does a match between two teams count as "multiple participants"? If not, does a tournament with final rankings count as one event with multiple participants, if several identical or highly similar tournaments are played in a series?

Comment: @Nij - these are good questions. I will edit the question to attempt to address these points. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variety of different sports run competitions in such a way.

## Golf

The PGA Tour is a series of golf tournaments, each one deciding a final rank for which points are assigned. [These points are aggregated over the season](https://www.pgatour.com/fedexcup/fedexcup-point-distribution--pga-tour-season.html); results from one tournament do not affect scores in another except to the extent that a player's aggregate score may determine whether they can gain entry to the event.

Toward the end of a season, the top band of players ranked by aggregate score are invited to further tournaments, at which their scores are reset according to a formula, and the process of aggregation continues. This culminates in a final tournament at which a cup is awarded and additional prize money given.

This may be directly compared with the auto-racing season: each individual tries to finish a fixed number of "laps" (the course) with the "quickest time" ( lowest number of shots). Points are given based on ascending order.

## Rugby 7s

The World Rugby Sevens Series are held across two calendar years (so that the previous series was 2016-17 and the upcoming series is 2017-18, for example).

Each of the ten tournaments in the series includes sixteen teams (men) or twelve teams (women). Each tournament has a classic pool-advance-to-knockouts structure.

Final placings in the tournament are [assigned points according to a fixed table](http://www.sarugby.co.za/article.aspx?id=1141551&leagueid=1021). These points are aggregated over a series and the team with the highest aggregate is the winner of the series.

## Surfing

The World Surf League holds a tour of events at which surfers are rated on various aspects of their performance. Several preliminary rounds determine quarterfinal places, from which the event proceeds as a knockout bracket.

Surfers are awarded [points according to a schedule](http://www.worldsurfleague.com/pages/rules-and-regulations), based on their placing at the event. A notable change is the award of points for being injured during the event. Points are aggregated over all tours with each surfer's worst two results (out of eleven events) being discarded. The surfer with the highest remaining aggregate is the champion.

Comment: While rugby is a two-competitor sport (I edited the question to try to communicate this clearer), I see that each event is played like competition between all teams at once, so I guess it is somewhat relevant here. I've edited in a link for surfing to a summary of their scoring system.

Comment: For golf, are the strokes simply added across the entire season, meaning that one very bad day can ruin the entire tournament?

Comment: Regarding golf, you're talking about two different things. Tournaments are played across a week or weekend. Seasons are played across a year. One bad day might ruin a tournament, but aside from the very last tournament, will have low if any impact on a season.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. I've found a source for this, so I'll edit that information in and accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The [Chess Grand Prix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_Grand_Prix_2017) takes place over a number of rounds and in each round, the players will play a number of matches and are awarded points based on their finishing position.

Though there is a debate to be had as to whether Chess is a sport, but I included it here anyway.

Comment: Whether people argue it elsewhere, it's been firmly decided that for our purposes, chess is not a sport.

Comment: This is very helpful information, but unfortunately isn't on topic for this site. [See here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-is-counted-as-sport) for the decision we made a number of years ago on chess, poker, etc.